# Are there examples of harmonic differential forms in non-singular projective algebraic varieties that appear in general relativity or quantum physics?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, kaluza-klein, algebraic-geometry

I would like to study some real physical examples of harmonic differential forms in non-singular projective algebraic varieties. As Calabi - Yau and Kahler manifolds are used in supersymmetry theories - string and supergravity, I suppose there will be examples from there. Perhaps there are examples from GR and QM also - hear kaluza - klein theory may be a place to look. It would be great if I can get a list or few specific examples from theories that have been experimentally verified and there is high confidence on their validity.